# Where is BSD socket functions defined on Linux?

Tags: linux

What is the library file name where BSD's socket(), recv(), send(), etc defined on Linux OS? (I'm using RedHat). Is the file located in /usr/lib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're in glibc (libc.so/libc.a). You don't need to link against anything special to use these functions on Linux.